# How do you replace HBox/VBox with Box/Grid

Tags: gtkmm

The documentation for [`HBox`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/unstable/classGtk_1_1HBox.html#details) and `VBox` includes the statement:

> Deprecated: Use Box instead, which is a very quick and easy change.
>   But we recommend switching to Grid, since Box will go away eventually.

However, it isn't obvious what the "quick and easy change" should be.

How do you use `Box` and/or `Grid` to achieve the functionality of `VBox` or `HBox`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the big changes in gtkmm3:

> Gtk::Box, Gtk::ButtonBox, Gtk::IconView, Gtk::Paned, Gtk::ProgressBar,
>   Gtk::ScaleButton, Gtk::ScrollBar and Gtk::Separator now derive from
>   Gtk::Orientable, allowing their orientation (vertical or horizontal)
>   to be specified without requiring the use of a derived class such as
>   Gtk::HBox.

Although Grid isn't mentioned above, both containers now have a method [set_orientation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/unstable/classGtk_1_1Orientable.html#ad6ab22a97e3811deda0dbc1b16571162); [Box](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/unstable/classGtk_1_1Box.html#a1080805aaf2c965f01183dc0d943ad80) can also take it in the constructor.  So for Box, set the orientation and use your usual `pack_start`, `pack_end`.

With Grid, if you [scrutinize the documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/unstable/classGtk_1_1Grid.html#details), you'll see this line:

> Grid can be used like a Box by just using Gtk::Container::add(), which
>   will place children next to each other in the direction determined by
>   the orientation property.

So, it should be as simple as setting the orientation and then `add` your child widgets.